# UI Application delegates not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

In one of my view controllers, I have inserted the following delegates:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Application Did Resign Active");
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Application Did Enter Background");
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Application Will Enter Foreground");
}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Application Did Become Active");
}
```

NSLog is showing none of the delegates ever being called. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to put these delegates in 'AppDelegate', they will be called there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in app delegate this methods will fire. And Using app delegate methods in multiple places is not advisable.

If you like to perform operations in your view controller based on the application action you can use notification like this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(customMethodsinViewController:) 
    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
    object: nil];
```

Comment: Ok. How would I do things like invalidate timers that were created in the view controller?

Comment: @PanicDev, you can invalidate timers in viewWillDisappear or in dealloc, depending on your needs.